# How can I add a UIImage to a grouped UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, interface-builder

I have a grouped UITableView that has 3 sections. I would like to show a UIImage with some text next to it (not a cell), but I am not sure how I can go about doing that? The image and text need to match the background of the pinstripes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A UITableView has a backgroundView property that it uses to display the pinstripes for the grouped style.  You can either replace the background view or add to it.  If you replace it, you lose the pinstripes.

```
[myTable.backgroundImage addSubview:myImage];
[myTable.backgroundImage addSubview:myLabel];
```

Comment: i added the UIImage to the tableview header

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to define a custom cell, you can use a standard [UITableViewCell](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  It has properties for text and an image.  Assign the image to the imageView property, put the text in the textLabel property.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your image and your desired placement, you can use the `imageView` property of the `UITableViewCell`.  Essentially, your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will look like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //Normal cell setup
    cell.imageView.image = myImage;
    cell.textLabel.text = imageDescription;
    return cell;
}
```

That will create a cell with an image at the left edge with text after it in the middle/right edge

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I want to place a UIImage and text outside of the cells. I want it to appear in the gray pinstripe area.

Answer (score 0):

[self.tableView addSubview:myImageView];
[Self.tableView sendSubviewToBack:myImageView];

Or

self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"myimage.png"]];

Use Photoshop to place something on top of an image of the pinstripes.